# MYSQL restrict use of CREATE, DROP, ALTER

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

My ISP offers just one user account for accessing a MYSQL database. AFAIK, I need to store the connection credentials for my database in clear text within my PHP code. Consequently, ordinary users of my site have administrative access to my database. They can't ordinarily misuse this access because the official backdoors I designed in require a password. [The way the password is used to authenticate a user is to search the database's list of users for the password hash and then see if the user is flagged as being an administrator.] But someone who is able to hack into the server's file system could read the PHP code and learn the password for the one and only user that my ISP provides.

Besides having two users with different permissions to the database, is there a way to bifurcate access so that superusers are the only ones able to do CREATE, ALTER, and DROP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to grant a limited set of privileges to most users, and the more destructive privileges to admin users.

You might like to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html to see the individual privilege types you can grant to users, and what operations they correspond to.

However, this doesn't really help if your app always connects using the same MySQL credentials, and then distinguishes the user by lookup of data in your database. MySQL's `GRANT` doesn't know anything about your app-level users, it only knows about the MySQL user, and that user has one set of privileges.

So it's up to you to control privileges per app-user in your code.

If your users gain illicit access and bypass your code, then they have whatever privileges granted to the MySQL user. There's no way you can control that.

It falls into the general category of "what if users have access to my filesystem?" If that's what you need to account for, then you can't let them have access to your filesystem. Implement your service as a software-as-a-service (SaaS).

Comment: I probably should have updated my question. I moved on to a different ISP and opted for a VPS, where I can use GRANT to my heart's content. Another part of my solution is to encrypt the MySQL connection credentials with a secret word that I can type in when I need full access. Users connect with a "secret" that is exposed in the HTML login script (hence not really secret), but they gain just the ability to do a SELECT on the table that lets them login.